# multipath -l vs -ll

Tags: linux, redhat, storage-area-network

What system information is `multipath -ll` reading that `multipath -l` does not?

From the [RHEL DM Multipath Guide](http://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/DM_Multipath/multipath_options.html)

```
-l   Display the current multipath configuration gathered from sysfs
     and the device mapper.

-ll  Display the current multipath configuration gathered from sysfs,
     the device mapper, and all other available components on the system.
```

Specifically, what does **"all other available components on the system"** include?

How can I update sysfs and device mapper so `multipath -l` reflects the true `[active][ready]` state of the links, instead of `[active][undef]`?